# Clalculating effective value of square waveform

Tags: signal

I need to calculate the effective value of this signal:

[image]

I dont know how to calculate this. Iknow how to calculate the effective value of well known waveforms like square, sin, ..., but this is a mystery for me. I think I should combine it somehow with square waveform, but I don't know how.

Comment: Integrate it. Integration of rectangles is dead simple.

Comment: The problem is: what is the function. The only information that I have is this picture. Can I read function from the picture somehow?

Comment: Height times width. And watch your signs.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you mean something like: +(10*1)+(0*2)+(-1*3)+(0*4)

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "effective value" because that's not how we usually talk about waveforms. Are you interested in this signal's ability to generate heat in a resistor? If so, then integration will not give you the result you want.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95731/how-to-calculate-the-average-of-a-square-wave

Comment: Little bit hard to translate for formel for effectiv value for square wavefor is U = sqrt(1/T * int from 0 to T u^2 dt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same of what Andy says above in details and with full equations. 
In electrical terms, the average (or mean) value of a periodic waveform is also known as the DC level of the waveform, even if it is zero. 
For example if you will try to charge a battery with a bipolar and symmetrical waveform, then there is no net charge on battery. 
So the average of the above waveform is

[image]

therefore

[image]

However, it is not the average current (or voltage) of an AC which determines its power delivering capability. The RMS value for a voltage or current waveform is the effective value from the point of view of power dissipation in a resistive circuit. 
So the effective or RMS current will be

[image]

results

[image]

But I have a question here: How we can apply

[image]

A practical use of the above is in rectifier circuits, that is shorten the contact time of diode, the power dissipation decreases but RMS current remains the same!

Answer (score 4):

There are two sections in the waveform that are not 0V then, I assume the waveform repeats. If you are calculating RMS then add the squares of the non-0V sections to get 100 + 4 = 104. Then, divide by baselength of 4 to get 26. Then take the square root to get 5.1V RMS.

For average it's 10 - 2 then divided by 4 = 2V